# Delphi iOS7 Launch image problems

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey-fm3

Under iOS7 it appears that the icon image is enlarged as a default launch image. My delphi app then adds the launch image setup in the project settings and what results is a mess on screen.

Is there a solution to this or a way to stop iOS from exploding the icon on startup?

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: And what is it supposed to look like? What's showing wrongly?

Comment: In the picture you can 2 two overlaying images. The crisp portrate image on top is the one setup in the IDE as the launch image.
Behind that is a blury landscape image that is an enlarged version of the app icon. When the app first starts the icon animates to this size and then the logo setup in the IDE is overlay on top.

Comment: I have the same problem when using assets - launch image appears together with big app logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it would appear that the only solution is to not use transparent png files. 
I am not sure if its a solution but I added a background to my launch files and the problem is masked.

Comment: Works for me too, and you should drag/select them once more in assets manager after adding background.